# How do I set extKeyUsage with phpseclib?

Tags: php, x509, phpseclib

I want to add the SSL Server and SSL Client flags to a cert that I am signing with phpseclib, how would I go about this? I found the setExtension function, but I dont know how to use it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I have tried the following and it doesnt work (mostly from the phpseclib example):

```
// create private key for CA cert
$CAPrivKey = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($CAPrivKey->createKey());
$CAPrivKey->loadKey($privatekey);

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($publickey);
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

echo "the private key for the CA cert (can be discarded):\r\n\r\n";
echo $privatekey;
echo "\r\n\r\n";


// create a self-signed cert that'll serve as the CA
$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo CA');

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($CAPrivKey);
$issuer->setDN($CASubject = $subject->getDN());

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');
$x509->setSerialNumber(chr(1));
$x509->makeCA();

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
echo "the CA cert to be imported into the browser is as follows:\r\n\r\n";
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
echo "\r\n\r\n";


// create private key / x.509 cert for stunnel / website
$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($privKey->createKey());
$privKey->loadKey($privatekey);

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($publickey);
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');
$subject->setDomain('www.google.com');

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($CAPrivKey);
$issuer->setDN($CASubject);

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');
$x509->setSerialNumber(chr(1));
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-extKeyUsage', array('id-kp-serverAuth', 'id-kp-clientAuth'));

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);

echo "the stunnel.pem contents are as follows:\r\n\r\n";
echo $privKey->getPrivateKey();
echo "\r\n";
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
echo "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd have to currently do is first create the X.509 cert, add the extensions to the X.509 cert after it's been created and then re-sign it. eg.

After `$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);` do this:

```
$x509->loadX509($result);

$x509->setExtension('id-ce-extKeyUsage', array('id-kp-serverAuth', 'id-kp-clientAuth'));

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $x509);
```

ie. you sign the cert, load it, set the extension, and then resign it.

Not an elegant solution unfortunately. It's my understanding that the API will, at some point, be updated to let you update extensions without having to first have the cert but that has yet to happen.